# Excel - convert ISO8601 date ending in Z into format suitable for entry into Postgres field with type 'timestamp with time zone'

Tags: excel, csv, datetime, iso8601

I have a CSV file that I'm opening in Excel. It has dates in this format:

`2019-09-15T00:11:57.4030000Z`

I want this:

`2019-09-15 00:11:57.403+00`

I think I may be able to use the "format cells > custom" option in Excel, but what would do I need to specify as the 'type' for the format? I tried using this to get most of it, but it doesnt' work:

`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000`

And when I try to apply some of the pre-existing types built into Excel, they don't seem to change the date format - it's as if the original date format isn't being recognised as valid.

Comment: That is because the string is text and not a true date/time.  You will need to parse the string to remove the T and the Z then convert to date/time.  Then you will be able to apply the correct format.

Comment: To add on on what @Scott Craner commented, since it is a structured format, you can just parse it with Left, Mid & Datevalue formulas

Comment: `=--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-5),"T"," ")`  Then format as desired.

Answer (score 0):

My OP asks how to do this in Excel, however I found it easier to parse the file with a regex. I used the excellent [dnGrep](https://dngrep.github.io/) tool for this, with the following pattern, that groups the date and time into substitution groups, then uses them in the replacement as `$1` and `$2` :

search - `([0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2})[T]([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3})[0-9]{4}Z`

replace - `$1 $2+00`